# Inline search and replace using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a password file and the entries like these ones that starts with `ENTP` should be manipulated.

Sample entry:

```
ENTP\username:VAS:1749078453:1749078453::/home/username:/bin/bash
```

to

```
ENTP\username:username_tst:1749078453:1749078453::/home/username:/bin/bash
```

i.e., we have to search and replace `VAS` to `username_tst` on all occurrences.

I know that we can do a search and replace using sed but I am confused on how to replace it with "username" from the first field. Is there a way we can do this in sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's easiest to use sed with the -r option

```
  -r, --regexp-extended 
      use extended regular expressions in the script
```

to avoid having to use many backslashed expressions:

`sed -r 's/(\\)(username)(:VAS:)/\1\2:\2_tst:/'`

Test:

```
$> echo "ENTP\username:VAS:1749078453:1749078453::/home/username:/bin/bash" | sed -r 's/(\\)(username)(:VAS:)/\1\2:\2_tst:/'
ENTP\username:username_tst:1749078453:1749078453::/home/username:/bin/bash
```

So now with your file you can do:

```
cat password_file | sed -r 's/(\\)(username)(:VAS:)/\1\2:\2_tst:/'
```

or:

```
sed -r 's/(\\)(username)(:VAS:)/\1\2:\2_tst:/' < password_file
```

If that looks good, you may do:

```
sed -r 's/(\\)(username)(:VAS:)/\1\2:\2_tst:/' < password_file > out_file
```